# Selenium - Unable to Create a remote session. [FF 53.0.2 + Geckodriver 0.16 + Selenium 3.4]

Tags: selenium, session, selenium-webdriver, grid, geckodriver

I can able to see the FF[53.0.2] opened. But, I am getting an "error Unable to create new remote session". Could any one help out?

Environment :
Windows 7 64 bit
FF - 53.0.2 (32bit)
Selenium 3.4
Geckdriver 0.16 and 0.16.1[win 32]

Problem :
Unable to create a new remote session. But, driver initiated the FF [blank browser].

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\Drivers\\geckodriver-‌v0.16.0-win32\\gecko‌​driver.exe"); 

DesiredCapabilities caps2 = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps2.setBrowserName("firefox"‌​);
caps2.setPlatform(‌​org.openqa.selenium.‌​Platform.WINDOWS);
dr‌​iver1= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node),caps2);
```

Actual output :

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, version=, platform=VISTA}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: Provide more information: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stack trace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to automate my testing scenarios in FF. i have FF version 53.0.2 installed in my machine. When i try to automate the scenarios using Selenium  3.4 and geckodriver 0.16 or 0.16.1. I am getting an error message '

Comment: Unable to create a new remote session. But, driver initiated the FF [blank browser]  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\Drivers\\geckodriver-v0.16.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe"); DesiredCapabilities caps2 = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();caps2.setBrowserName("firefox");caps2.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);driver1= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node),caps2);

Comment: Can you update all these information in the question area for proper analysis? Try upgrading Mozilla Firefox to 53.0 as well, Thanks

Comment: @Dev - I tried updating the FF to 53.0 still the same issue.

Comment: I just saw you are using `RemoteWebDriver`, are you using Selenium Grid configuration?

Comment: @Dev - Yes i am using Remote WebDriver. Also, i did tried using a normal Firfox call    driver =new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: My suggestion would be start with basics first, learn & grow then move to complex usecases like Selenium Grid.

Comment: @Dev- Even on the basics i am unable to run the script in FF.

Comment: I will suggest you to edit your question Heading and Description (keep it simple, remove `Remote`) then I can provide you an expected Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try replacing this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\Drivers\\geckodriver-‌​v0.16.0-win32\\gecko‌​driver.exe");
```

With this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "explicit path to your geckodriver);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved.While setting up a node, i gave the configuration as geckodriver-‌​v0.16.1-win32. Irrespective of setting other properties, it didn't change.Simple one, but i took a long way to explore. Anyways, thank you guys.